# high current PCB traces: do we need many?

Tags: pcb, high-current

According to some calculations on this site (using standardized IPC-2221) it seems that a set of parallel traces handles more current than if they are joined in a single trace. Why?
https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

For example for 2A we need 0.391mm but for 20A we need way more than 10X the width (9.36 mm)

How this can be explained?

Comment: Different ratio of surface area (and PCB area) to conductor cross section. So it can dissipate more heat.

Answer (score 14):

> A set of parallel traces handles more current than if they are joined in a single trace. Why?

> For 2A (*) we need 0.391mm but for 20A we need way more than 10X the width (9.36 mm).  How this can be explained?

This can be explained by the missing bit here: (*).

This is not for 2A only, but also for a certain *temperature rise* at 2A.  Heat is not radiated equally (linearly) between small conductors and large conductors.  The larger (wider) the conductor, the more it heats itself.  Copper is a great conductor of heat, but not the best radiator of it.

So that is why adding a second 2A trace results in more than 2x the current rating: these traces are spread out over a larger area, thus reducing their temperature. So more current can go through this pair for the same temperature rise.

For traces which must carry 20A, often a work-around is used such as external wiring / bus bars / thicker copper / etc.  I once saw a "power" board with 0.75mm (0.030") thick copper.  Exotic and expensive, but necessary.

Comment: OP wanted an *intuitive* explaination, that is why this is a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

The relationship between the geometry of the trace, the current going through it, and its temperature rise is non-trivial.

The standard formulas of IPC-2221 are the result of empirical study which gave a practical formula and the constants:

I = k(ΔT)<sup>0.44</sup>A<sup>0.725</sup>

- I = maximum current in Amps
- T = temperature °C
- A = cross-sectional area in mils-squared
- k = 0.024 (internal layer), 0.048 (external)

For a detailed analysis, read

- "New Correlations Between Electrical Current and Temperature Rise in PCB Traces", Johannes Adam, in *IEEE 20th IEEE SEMI-THERM Symposium*, 2004.
  [PDF](https://web.ics.purdue.edu/%7Egblack/Trace%20Temp%20Study.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Ampacity is estimated for a single long trace in the middle of a board.  If you put two traces together in parallel, close together, they will heat each other: temp rise increases.  Using the basic calculation and using two traces in parallel, assumes they are far enough apart that they do not heat each other.  So the heat flows out over a much wider space, and thinner traces can be used than for a single wider trace.

Note the other case this does not apply to: short traces, where the heat spreads along its length, say into component leads/pads or wide pours.  The temp rise or fusing current of a small neck is vastly greater than predicted from the same trace width!

Which is also basically why, for example, component leads can be so diminutive (TO-220 leads aren't even 18 AWG equivalent) yet can handle immense currents (the fuse rating for this package is over 50A).

Note that IPC-2221 is obsolete; IPC-2152 is generally considered better, but neither works for a complex board, for the above reason.  If you really need to know the temp rise, you need a multiphysics (thermal and electric) model of the PCB.  Or, as most of us do -- design it by rules of thumb, and check that the real thing behaves well enough in person.  Tolerable temp rise is quite loose (does it *really* matter if the temp rise is 5, 10 or 20°C?) so the precision of a simulator is rarely warranted.